# Masking data on an IQueryable but retaining the ability to filter on masked data

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I have an oData endpoint that returns an IQueryable of my users. I need to mask sensitive data that gets returned and have chosen the approach that can be seen below.

```cs
public IQueryable<User> Get()
{
    return _defaultContext.Users
             .AsQueryable()
             .Select(x => new User
             {
                 Id = x.UserId,
                 FirstName = x.FirstName,
                 SecondName = x.SecondName,
                 EmailAddress = x.EmailAddress != null ?
                                x.EmailAddress.Substring(0, 3) + "*****" +
                                x.EmailAddress.Substring(int.Parse((x.EmailAddress.IndexOf("@").ToString()))) :
                                string.Empty,
                 MobilePhone = x.MobilePhone != null ?
                               "*** *** " +
                               x.MobilePhone.Substring(x.MobilePhone.Length - 4) :
                               string.Empty,
                 IdentityNumber = x.IdentityNumber.Substring(0, 3) +
                                  " *** *** " +
                                  x.IdentityNumber.Substring(x.IdentityNumber.Length - 4),
                 IdNumberTypeId = x.IdentityTypeId,
                 DateOfBirth = x.DateOfBirth,
                 CountryOfIssue = x.CountryOfIssue.IsoCode
             });
}
```

The problem I have now is I cant filter on the masked data when making a **GET** call like I can on the unmasked data.

```
https://myurl.com/odata/v2.3/user?$select=Id,FirstName,SecondName,EmailAddress,MobilePhone,IdentityNumber&$skip=0&$top=10&$count=true&$filter=indexof(tolower(FirstName), '2') gt -1 or indexof(tolower(SecondName), '2') gt -1 or indexof(tolower(IdentityNumber), '2') gt -1&$orderby=Id asc&_=1622190148820
```

Is there a way to get around this problem, whether its a better way of masking the chosen sensitive data or something else I'm missing?

Comment: You need to apply the masking as the last step. You can try and have it as an extension method so you have something like `usersQuery.ApplyFilters().MaskData()`

Comment: On the other hand, if you can filter on masked data then I can guess it. Maybe not the address entirely, but the phone number, for instance, can be obtained through filtering. E.g.: I apply the filter with a full phone number, returned users will have that phone number, so much for security.